# Is sp_helptext reliable?

Tags: sql-server

I use sp_helptext a lot because it's so much faster than clicking through the Object Explorer trees. However, I just had a case where a stored proc name had been changed and the result from sp_helptext still contained the old name. I was a bit confused at first as I tried to alter it and it said the object didn't exist until I realized it still had the old name.

Interestingly, when I used the Object Explorer to script the object the result was correct.

Is there a way I can get the same correct results from a T-SQL statement? And if not, can I assume this issue is probably limited to renaming, but that I can otherwise always trust sp_helptext to give correct results?

And, yes, I understand some might contend that sp_helptext *is* giving the "correct" result because it's the text the proc was created with. You know what I'm looking for though, lol. No need to split hairs.

Comment: This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and expected behaviour, and is 1 reason why renaming such objects is not recommended.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, I actually I wish I could make the default behavior for renaming in the Object Explorer to drop and recreate the object rather than to "rename" it. I typically do it when creating new stuff that doesn't have any dependencies yet when I realize a better name or see a typo or what have you.